# Do any non-Euclidean "$p$-ish" norms not distinguish the axes?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be the real numbers or the complex numbers, let $S$ be a set with at least two elements,

let ​ $\hspace{.04 in}f : [0,\hspace{-0.04 in}\scriptsize+\normalsize \infty) \to [0,\hspace{-0.04 in}\scriptsize+\normalsize \infty)$ ​ be an [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) such that ​ $\hspace{.04 in}f(1) = 1$ ,

let $V$ be the set of functions ​ $v : S\to \mathbb{K}$ ​ such that [$\;\;\; \displaystyle\sum_{s\in S}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Families_of_non-negative_numbers) $\hspace{.04 in}f(|v(s)|) \; < \; \scriptsize+\normalsize \infty \;\;\;$,

assume $V$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{K}^S$, and suppose that

$||\hspace{-0.05 in}\cdot\hspace{-0.05 in}|| : V\to [0,\hspace{-0.04 in}\scriptsize+\normalsize \infty)$ ​ is a norm such that for all vectors $v$ in $V\hspace{-0.03 in}$, $\;\;\; \hspace{.04 in}f(||v||) \; =$ [$\;\displaystyle\sum_{s\in S}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Families_of_non-negative_numbers) $\hspace{.04 in}f(|v(s)|)$

and for that norm, there is an isometric automorphism which is **not** a

[generalized permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix) operator whose non-zero entries all have absolute-value $1$.

> Does it follow that for all elements $x$ of $[0,\hspace{-0.04 in}\scriptsize+\normalsize \infty)$, ​ $\hspace{.04 in}f(x) = x^2$ ?

(I came up with that question during linear algebra class when the professor mentioned that

the $p$-norm analogue of the Pythagorean theorem holds *for vectors with disjoint [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Formulation)*.)